# Display "Not Provided" when variable is null or empty in database

Tags: php, arrays, database, foreach

i have a variable array that gets all what my function has retrieved.

```
$array = $funcs->searchCompany($bizName);
```

and then i used foreach to check if the value is null for varchar and 0 for int and then i replace its value to "Not Provided" so that everytime it is being called it will say "Not Provided"

```
foreach ($array as $var) {
            if($var == " " || $var == 0) {
                $var = "Not Provided";
            }
         }

  $name = $var['name'];
            $url = $var['url'];
            $tagline = $var['tagline'];
            $descrip = $var['descrip'];
            $bemail = $var['bemail'];
            $address = $var['address'];
            $city = $var['city'];
```

but it seems wrong because it destroys the output instead.

Comment: Instead you can simply use `if(empty($var))`

Comment: I think that you think that you're changing the values of the array items in the `foreach` loop. But this is not the case, the `$var` in that loop is a new variable assigned with the value of the array item (not a pointer).

Comment: Also is this the real code? Because the `$var` inside the foreach is not the `$var` variable you use below it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&` here to pass the value of array to change inside foreach without actually worrying about which is the current array key, which is also sometimes called as passing a variable's value by reference.

**Using** `foreach`

```
foreach ($array as &$value) // note the &
{
    if(empty($value)) $value = 'Not Provided';
    // other values remain untouched
}
```

**Using** `array_map()`

```
$array = array_map(function($value){
            if(empty($value))
                return 'Not Provided';
            return $value;
        }, $array);
```

But i will suggest to go with foreach.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this . I can not write comments so I am writing it as an answer.

What I understand from your code is your array has key value relation. That is most probably why it is not working with your single dimensional array iteration.
try this instead.

```
    foreach ($array as $var => $value) {
         if($value == " " || $value == 0 || $value == null) {
             $array[$var] = "Not Provided";
         }
      }
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($array);
   echo "</pre>";
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

update your function so something like

```
foreach ($array as &$var) {
    if($var == " " || $var == 0) {
        $var = "Not Provided";
    }
}

$name = $array['name'];
$url = $array['url'];
$tagline = $array['tagline'];
$descrip = $array['descrip'];
$bemail = $array['bemail'];
$address = $array['address'];
$city = $array['city'];
```